# Why does LOAD time address binding methods generate identical Logical and Physical Address

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I have recently started learning OS and in memory management chapter from silberschatz I got confused between identical and different addresses(Logical and Physical) of load time and run time binding respectively.

Specifically, In load time binding if MMU relocates the logical address (e.g. 300) to physical address( to 14346 if relocation register has value of 14000) then how does these 2 addresses are identical.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming related question. This belongs in some other stack or forum.

Comment: @WaleedIqbal Can you please specify the stack/forum to which I should tag this question. I have no idea how to do so. Thank you

Comment: Try https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why is it that so many people read Silberschatz and are confused yet so many people continue to read it? I'm confused just reading this question. Poster, you are going to have to provide a lot more context for us to figure out what this confusing book is trying to say.

Comment: well this is what my University recommends  :p As far as I know, Logical address lies in b/w 0-MAX and Physical add after relocation lies in b/w R-(R+MAX). So how are the 2 same?

Comment: You are going to have to give a lot more information. What you are describing is a method of memory management that does not exist any more.

Comment: what other information do you need? I can't understand.

Comment: @jazz1997 What architecture are you addressing to? Usually MMU works through page tables. What is relocation register? What do you put in "load time binding"? Seriously, if you are really interested in the topic, you may check how it works in Linux for example https://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html

Comment: @AlexHoppus Well the architecture was not specified in the book. And I got the answer from the link you shared :D Thank you.