# How are logical and physical address same in load time address binding?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I am learning Operating System basics. Following is what i know about load time address binding.

**Load time address binding**:
In this type of binding, compiler generates relocatable code and while loading the compiled code in main memory actual binding take place, where loader adds base address in all relocatable addresses.
**So, Here is my question:**
Suppose, CPU generates logical address x(which is also a relocatable address) from compiled code and MMU would have the base address y same as loader and limit register as 0. Hence, MMU would point physical address as x+y. So, here logical address is x and physical address came out as x+y then how are logical address and physical address same at load time binding.

I found same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004697/why-does-load-time-address-binding-methods-generate-identical-logical-and-physic) but it is unanswered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have reality (e.g. physical memory), but on top of reality you build an elaborate illusion (e.g. virtual memory) to ensure that nothing else has to care about reality and everything else only ever sees the illusion.

On top of the illusion; the OS loads stuff from a file to "virtual address x" and does load time address binding to patch things to work at "virtual address x"; but none of this has any reason to care about reality or physical addresses.

Underneath the illusion; maybe "virtual address x" ends up being "physical address y"; and maybe "virtual memory" is a mixture of real/physical RAM and swap space and other stuff; and maybe pieces of "virtual memory" are frequently bouncing between different physical places (RAM, disk, ..). As long as it creates the illusion of "memory" it doesn't matter much and nothing built on top (load time binding) has a reason to care.

Comment: Whatever you are saying is right but quite abstract. You are saying to consider mapping as black box and don't care what going inside that. But i what to know what going inside that in order to learn OS course. I want to know how MMU is doing mapping in case of load time binding. I think my question is clear.

Comment: @deepakjnv880: What I'm suggesting is that you should learn to create virtual address spaces and manage them (without caring about load-time address binding), then learn about executable file loaders and load-time address binding (without caring about physical addresses, etc); and that there's no benefit in combining them and trying to learn both at the same time and getting confused for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have read same in my textbook and my interpretation is that this is all talking bout in the context of segmentation and not paging! So:

1. Compile time: here we know the physical address at the time of compilation, so we create absolute (physical) address at the first time while compilation only!
2. Load time: in this case, yes, we generate relative address at the time of compilation. But, while loading, since we know the physical address at the time of loading (as the program is not gonna relocated after loading while execution), we calculate and replace the relative address with absolute address, and hence in this case as well the logical address (CPU generated address) will be the same as physical address.

So that's my interpretation...